# How to fix ear deployement error in JBoss7.1 when there is a clash for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Tags: spring-boot, logging, java-8, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to deploy an ear file in JBoss. 
My project structure is jar>war>ear. 
In the war file I have webapp>WEB-INF>jboss-deployment-structure.xml where I have mentioned

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

when I deploy the **war** file in the JBOSS, it deploys it fine.

But when I try to deploy the **ear** file having the war file inside.
It is giving the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: Unable to instantiate implementation class for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:378)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:328)
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getClassLoader(LogFactory.java:401)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getClassLoader(LogFactoryImpl.java:392)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.initDiagnostics(LogFactoryImpl.java:420)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.<init>(LogFactoryImpl.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:153)
```

I used to get the same error when deploying the **war** file, which was fixed by the xml file. But now while deploying the ear file I am getting the same error. Any pointers will help

Comment: What version of JBoss are you using?

Comment: JBOSS 7.1.0 Application server

Comment: Do you mean JBoss EAP 7.1? If so this might be of interest https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-14458.

Comment: yeah...I loaded the latest commons-logging jar as per the suggestion and the error is fixed now